UVM testbench for APB driver run_phase logic
In the driver_class run_phase code below, I am not able to understand how to write the logic to send the transaction to the DUT.

Can we give Penable, Psel, Pready values manually in the driver class or can we randomize those in seq_item class?
If we give values according the different states like idle, setup and access.

task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    
         //forever begin
    repeat(4) begin
           `uvm_info("driver Class", "run_phase", UVM_MEDIUM)
         
           seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);
      
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        @(posedge vif.P_clk)//ideal
          {vif.P_selx,vif.P_enable,vif.P_write}<=0;
      #5;
          
        @(posedge vif.P_clk)//setup
          vif.P_selx<=1;
          vif.P_addr<=req.P_addr;
          vif.P_wdata<=req.P_wdata;
      
      repeat(4)
        begin
          req.randomize();
          
          @(posedge vif.P_clk)//access-write
          vif.P_enable<=1;
          vif.P_write<=1;
          vif.P_wdata<=req.P_wdata; 
          vif.P_addr<=req.P_addr;
      
    
          @(posedge vif.P_clk)//setup
          vif.P_enable<=0;
        end
      
      repeat(10)
        begin
        
        req.randomize(); 
          @(posedge vif.P_clk)//access-read
          vif.P_enable<=1;
          vif.P_write<=0;  
          vif.P_addr<=req.P_addr;
          vif.P_wdata<=req.P_wdata;
      
          @(posedge vif.P_clk)//setup
          vif.P_enable<=0;
      
      
      end

          
        
          `uvm_info(get_type_name(),$sformatf("run phase of driver P_addr=%0d P_rst=%0d P_clk=%0d P_wdata=%0d P_write=%0d P_rdata=%0d ",req.P_addr,req.P_rst,req.P_clk,req.P_wdata,req.P_write,req.P_rdata),UVM_LOW);
           
           seq_item_port.item_done();
           
           
         end
       endtask


It is more common to call randomize in the sequence class than in the UVM agent driver class.  If your goal is to create an agent that other people can use as well, it would be unexpected behavior for the driver to call randomize.
The sequence item class could also have rand properties for psel and pwrite.
It is also unexpected to see all those repeat loops in the driver.  It looks like you are driving multiple APB transfers from within the driver.  It is more common for the driver to only drive a single transfer (sequence item).  The sequence class should have the loops for multiple sequence items.
